# I can login to Mojang but can't login to Minecraft.net

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I bought Minecraft yesterday and had so much fun. I heard about skins from my friend and decided to change it. I went to minecraft.net and tried to log-in, but I couldn't. I logged in succesfully at account.mojang.com though. I also bought Minecraft at account.mojang.com too with a gamecard at Walmart. How do I migrate my mojang account to Minecraft?

Comment: Minecraft login severs have been having trouble.  That might be the issue.

Comment: Did you use your email account to log in? If you try to use your Minecraft name it won't work.

Comment: When you say that you "couldn't" log in, what does that mean? Unknown username/password? Site timing out?

Answer (score 1):

You would not "migrate your mojang account to Minecraft," your Mojang account *is* your Minecraft account. Log into minecraft.net using your Mojang account. Make sure to use your email address as your username. If it's still not working, check that the servers are up. https://help.mojang.com/

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. Just log in with your e-mail address and password. Then you may need to answer a security question. If this fails then check your internet is running ok.

Answer (score -1):

Mojang appears to be having trouble with their servers right now. You might want to wait and try again later when their [servers all show green](https://help.mojang.com/).